# Which of these Feynman diagrams are correct?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, feynman-diagrams

The first is from a textbook, the second is from Wikipedia.

[image: Feynman diagram one]

[image: Feynman diagram two]

Intuitively, I think the textbook one is correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct", and why do you think one of them is not?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Both diagrams are representing beta(-) decay, however, the latter diagram has the direction of the anti-electron neutrino going downwards, opposed to the direction of the first diagram going upwards.

Comment: And what are the conventions of the respective sources for what the arrow represents? It's impossible to tell whether one of these diagrams is "wrong" unless you tell us what the source thinks the arrow actually *means*!

Comment: Oh, I thought that the arrows on Feynman diagrams could only represent direction, so I took that as an assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wikipedia diagram shows the arrow on the antineutrino pointing downward, towards the vertex. This follows the convention that the arrow shows the direction of flow for the particle, and antiparticles have backward arrows. The textbook uses the more obvious technique of using the arrow to show the direction of travel. Perhaps not wrong, if you say what you're doing, but not the usual convention (and what do you do with internal lines?) The textbook caption just says 'diagram' not 'Feynman diagram'.

[image]

For example, this shows the Feynman diagram for electron positron annihilation into 2 photons (reading left-to-right rather than bottom-to-top). The 3 arrowed lines trace the path of a conserved electron current. The top is an electron, the bottom a positron, and the intermediate one represents both an electron going from the upper vertex to the lower and a positron going from the lower to the upper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm still a little unclear on what you mean by "direction of flow of the particle [by convention]". Is it a rule we follow for antiparticles?

Comment: Yes. I've added a bit to the answer as one can't put graphics in a comment,

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense to me now. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. The wikipedia one takes into account the fact that the proton and the neutron are composite particles and describes the proton decay as for the Standard Model. In the wikipedia one there're more details, so per say.

Edit: the textbook one seems to imply with the direction of the arrow the spatial direction of the outgoing and ingoing particles. The wikipedia one uses the Feynman diagrams in momentum space so the antiparticles have ingoing arrows for outgoing particles and viceversa.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I still don't fully understand why the particle being composite or elementary would change the direction of the particle. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The direction of the arrow depends on whether there's a fermion or an antifermion, it does not depend on the fact that a particle is composite or not. The outgoin antineutrino has ingoing arrow in the vertex since it's an antifermion, on the contrary the outgoing electron has outgoing arrow from the vertex begin a fermion. And same goes for the quarks: the ingoing neutron quarks go into the vertex since they are fermions and the outgoing proton ones go outside of the vertex since they are fermions as well.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the help!